# Smoothly clipped absolute deviation(SCAD)

Tags: machine-learning, regularization

Hi i am working with Scad penalty but i am confused whether this penalty is concave or non-concave,or whether the penalty is concave when used in the least squares framework and non-concave in the frame work of likelihood? any type of help is highly appreciated to solve the confusion.